# Custom scaffold for controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using repository pattern in my ASP MVC4 app and I thought it would be nice to create custom scaffold templates to avoid tweaking code every time I generate something.

I followed some tutorials from the web. I copied the CodeTemplates directory form ProgramFiles to my project (only some of the files) and I cleared the Custom Tool property for each.

I managed to achieve 2 goals:

- override the default template for controller: when I go to Controller>Add>Controllers and select "controller with read/write actions and views...." it uses my template.
- add a new view template: when I go to SomeViewFolder>Add>View I can choose my new template there.

The thing I was unable to achieve was to create a new template **ControllerWithRepo.tt** and be able to select it in Controller>Add>Controllers. Even though I have **ControllerWithRepo.tt** created it doesn't show up on the template drop down list.

I know it's possible to do what I want by hardcoding things in **ControllerWithContext.tt**  , but it seems to be a lame solution. I would like to do it the right way - to pass a repository class instead of DbContext class and generate the controller the way I want.

Right now If I try to put my repository class as dbcontext it fails to perform the scaffold.

To sum up, how can I create my own controller scaffold template for repository pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to override the existing ControllerWithRepository by following Steve Sandererson's [post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/04/06/mvcscaffolding-overriding-the-t4-templates/) on *Overriding the T4 templates*.